# Why do the Beta and Binomial densities look exactly the same?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, beta-function

Consider a coin. The coin has a probability $Q$ of showing us a heads when tossed. The coin is tossed $N$ times and results in $H$ heads. First, what is the distribution of $H$ given $N$ and $Q$. This is just the Binomial distribution:

$$P(H | Q, N) = \frac{N!}{H!(N-H)!}Q^H(1-Q)^{N-H} \tag{1}$$

Next, what is the distribution of $Q$ given $N$ and $H$? This is Beta and we have (replacing the Gamma functions in the Beta function with factorials since $N$ and $H$ are integers here):

$$P(Q | N, H) = \frac{N!}{H!(N-H)!}Q^H(1-Q)^{N-H} \tag{2}$$

And we get the exact same expression as in equation (1). <s>We can mechanically prove this with Bayes theorem, sure</s> (I don't know how to do even this).

But the two expressions are completely different. The first is a probability mass function and the second one is a probability density function. It is very strange that they look the same. Is this suggestive of some general result for distributions when we consider various parameters fixed and try to get the distributions of others? Or is it just a fluke occurrence in this particular case with the Binomial and Beta?

Comment: This is close to what is called "conjugacy" in Bayesian statistics.  You have to specify a distribution for $Q$ before you can use Bayes' rule though.

Comment: Let's say the distribution of $Q$ is uniform.

Comment: That is perfect because uniform distribution is a special case of beta: $\text{Beta}(1, 1)$. I will try and elaborate in an answer soon

Comment: Your second claim, the conditional distribution of $Q$ given parameters $N$ and $H$, is incorrect, because the resulting beta density will be
$$f_Q(q \mid n,h) = \frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(h+1)\Gamma(n-h+1)} q^h (1-q)^{n-h} = \frac{(n+1)!}{h! (n-h)!} q^h (1-q)^{n-h}, \quad 0 < q < 1.$$  Your expression is missing a factor of $n+1$.

Comment: Ahh right. That is annoying. A similar thing happens in the Gamma to Poisson where the two look almost exactly the same, barring one additional term.

Comment: @RohitPandey For the gamma, poisson are you using a gamma prior on the poisson parameter $\lambda$?  Because if you use a uniform prior $\lambda \sim U(0, 1)$, you can be misled: the posterior can look like a gamma but it actually isn't because its support would be on $(0, 1)$ whereas gamma support is $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: I'm not using any priors, simply eyeballing the density functions from Wikipedia. If you replace the $k$ in the Gamma PDF with $i+1$,  you get something that looks very close to the Poisson PMF barring one term.

Answer (score 2):

This is close to a classic example of what is called **conjugacy** in Bayesian statistics. In your case, you did not give a distribution for the random variable $Q \in (0, 1)$; that would be called a **prior**. In fact, it is customary to give $Q$ a beta prior i.e. suppose $Q \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ for known $\alpha, \beta > 0$. Now suppose $N \in \mathbb Z_+$ and $H \in \mathbb N$ is a random variable such that
$$
H \ | \ Q = q \sim \text{Binomial}(N, q)
$$ Then something nice happens when you try to calculate $Q \ | \ H = h$; for $q \in (0, 1)$
\begin{align*}
p_{Q}(q \ | \ h) &= \frac{p_Q(q)p_H(h \ | \ q)}{p_H(h)}\\
&\propto_q p_Q(q)p_H(h \ | \ q) \\
&\propto_q q^{\alpha - 1}(1 - q)^{\beta - 1} q^h (1 - q)^{N - h} \\
&= q^{(\alpha + h) - 1}(1 -q)^{(\beta + N - h) - 1}
\end{align*} and this is the kernel of a $\text{Beta}(\alpha + h, \beta + N - h)$. So $[Q \ | \ H = h] \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha + h, \beta + N - h)$. Note that in each step of the derivation, I ignored constants that do not contain $q$. You don't always need the exact constants to recognize the form (aka **kernel**) of a distribution.

In other words starting with a beta prior on $Q$ with binomial data, you have ended up with a beta **posterior** on $Q$. In the special case where $\alpha = \beta = 1$, you have the uniform prior on $Q$.